# if doc has children remove all children and if children has more children remove those children

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

My Collection has following structure

```
{
 _id:1,
 parent_id:0
}
{
 _id:2,
 parent_id:1
}
{
 _id:3,
 parent_id:1
}
{
 _id:4,
 parent_id:3
}
```

Like

a > a1 > a1-1,a1-2,a1-3 > a11

One parent has many children and the childrens can have many childrens infinite loop

but when user clicks on a I want to delete all its children and it childrens too

I tried following function

```
var deleteChildCards = function(id){
    var count=userCards.find({parent_id: id}).count();
    if(count > 0){
        userCards.find({parent_id: id}).forEach(function (card) {
            deleteChildCards(card._id);
        });
    }
    else{
        return userCards.remove({_id: id});
    }
}
```

If I pass id to the function it must remove all it's childs,This is not removing all docs what is wrong in this function.

Is there any other way I can write this function?

Comment: Did you try using hooks? Forget about that ifs:forEach and use hooks

Comment: Would you expand on that please, @Ethaan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the `else` portion of the if-else will never get run. Try the following adjustment:

```
var deleteChildCards = function(id) {
  userCards.find({parent_id: id}).forEach(function(card) {
    deleteChildCards(card._id);
    userCards.remove(card._id);
  });
}
```

You can completely eliminate the if-else in this example since the forEach won't iterate if there are no userCards found.

Comment: For safety, you could do the call to `userCards.remove` before the recursive call. This should avoid getting stuck in an infinite loop if there would be cycles in the data (i.e., a has b and parent and b has a as parent). Also, it should be `userCards.remove({_id: card._id})`, right?

Comment: The first argument passed into `userCards.remove` is the selector. If you only pass in a string or Mongo.ObjectID, then it automatically matches that to _id. See [Mongo-Style Selectors](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/selectors) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you did if else by mistake.

Try

```js
var deleteChildCards = function(id){
    var count=userCards.find({parent_id: id}).count();
    if(count > 0){
        userCards.find({parent_id: id}).fetch().forEach(function (card) {
            deleteChildCards(card._id);
        });
    }
        userCards.remove({_id: id});
}
```

Otherwise, it will only remove the cards at the lowest level of the hierarchy. 
Also, you need to do .fetch() after find(), if you want to do forEach